# Android application crashes when trying to connect rtmp

Tags: android, video-streaming, red5, rtmp

Here is my problem,
I am trying to connect my android application to the red5 server,
Here is my code

```
import com.al.rtmp.client.RtmpClient;
import com.al.rtmp.client.RtmpStream;
import com.al.rtmp.client.RtmpStreamFactory;
import com.al.rtmp.client.data.MetaData;
import com.al.rtmp.client.data.RTMPData;
import com.al.rtmp.client.data.VideoCodec;
import com.al.rtmp.message.Metadata;
...

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
RtmpStream stream = null;
String server = "rtmp://192.168.0.168/red5test/";
...
public void mytestfunction(){
.
.
.
stream = RtmpStreamFactory.getRtmpStream();
stream.setClient(this);
stream.connect(server);
.
.
.
}
}
```

Eclipse shows no error, but application crashes runtime at `stream.connect(server)`
on log cat, the error is shown like

```
Android Runtime at yes.x.g(Unknown source)
Android RUntime at yes.x.connect(Unknown source);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Posting the `caused by` lines would be much more useful, can you share those? Do you have the `INTERNET` permission in your `AndroidManifest`?